# Launchd starts event 40 seconds later?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, vpn, launchd

I've created a `.plist` file, which should act as system daemon (global with `root` user). This `.plist` file listens to the `settings` directory for changes like changing network settings. When this happens it should start a Bash script.

However, it works but not as expected. When I open a VPN connection it takes about 40 seconds until the Bash script will be executed. I would like it to be executed right after I open the VPN connection.

How to remove the delay before the launch?

Here is the code of `.plist` file:

```
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>lucafuhl.vpnhelper</string>
            <key>Program</key>
            <string>/Users/vpnhelper.sh</string>
        <key>WatchPaths</key>
            <string>/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration</string>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

Comment: Please provide your .plist file so we can see what properties you are using.

Comment: What file inside of SystemConfiguration are you monitoring changes for?  Is it possible that the file isn't modified until 40 secs after the VPN is established?

Comment: From what I know about this system, I watch all the file in `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration`. I don't know exactly which file is changing. That was the way I found here on stackexchange

Comment: This isn't a strong area for me but if there's a problem in your plist configuration file, an easier way of creating it would be to use LaunchControl [http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/] - see also launchd.info.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

Try placing your

```
<string>/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration</string>
```

inside an

```
<array> 
</array>
```

Additionally you may be able to watch to see when the change actually happens with the below command.

```
sudo fs_usage -f filesys | grep /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration
```